# « Demander de » vs « demander que » plus subjonctif

Tags: subjonctif, infinitif, de

1)

> Je lui demande de venir.
>
> Je demande qu'il vienne.

Quelle est la différence ?

2)

> Je lui ai demandé de venir.
>
> J'ai demandé qu'il vienne.
>
> J'ai demandé qu'il soit venu.

Quelles sont les différences ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Dans le deuxième cas, la demande n'est pas forcément directement adressée à la personne en question. Un tiers peut être chargé de transmettre ou exécuter la demande.

2) idem pour la différence entre les deux premières phrases. La troisième n'est pas utilisable. On ne peut pas *être venu par quelqu'un* mais on peut dire :

> J'ai demandé qu'il soit conduit jusqu'ici.

Answer (score 1):

La différence n'est pas tant sur le plan sémantique que sur le plan grammatical. Je veux dire que ce n'est pas le tant le sens qui va commander l'infinitif ou le subjonctif que la façon dont la phrase est construite.

Ce qui suit la demande s'appelle : une **complétive**. Dans tes exemples, elle fera fonction de COD.
On peut construire cette complétive de deux manières :

-a) **de** (voire **à** dans certains cas) + **infinitif**

-b) **que** + **SUJET** + **subjonctif**.

La forme b) est la plus courante mais on peut les utiliser indifféremment à deux exceptions près :

- Si le sujet de la complétive (ou ce qui va faire l'action de la complétive) est le même que celui de la principale.
- Si ce qui doit subir l'action de la complétive est le même que le COI de la principale.

Dans ces deux cas, la solution b) est irrégulière et a) la seule possible :

Tu réalises donc que tout dépend beaucoup de comment tu as construit ta principale.

Dans les exemples que tu donnes, tu es conscient qu'il te faut préciser à qui s'adresse la demande. Tu décides qu'il doit être précisé :

Tu peux donc légitimement décider d'en faire Soit :

- Le COI de la principale,
- Le sujet de la complétive.

Soit l'un, soit l'autre, ensuite, tout n'est plus que pure grammaire à dérouler :

- Si tu fourgues le COI dans ta principale, celui qui va subir l'action de la complétive est le même => pas le choix => construction a) obligatoire par exigence grammaticale.
- Si tu ne mets pas l'information dans la principale alors il faut la mettre en tant que sujet dans la complétive, pas le choix => construction b) obligatoire par construction grammaticale.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette réponse exhaustive ☺!